# Multiplying all values in a column in Excel by a number

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, multiplication

[image]

I want to multiply all the cells from B5 onwards by D2, and put the results from C5 onwards. How would I do this in Excel using a formula? Sorry if this is off topic, but this has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Do you want each cell in the range B5:B9 to be individually multiplied by the value in D2, and then have the result in the corresponding cell in the range C5:C9?

Comment: @MJD: Yes, but preferably with a formula that will work for all the values I enter in column B...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a separate cell with say "5".  Copy this cell.
Select the column to multiply and right click -> Paste Special -> Paste Special.
Under operations, choose multiply.

Note: You can also choose just a selection, if wanted.

So in your case:

- Copy D2
- Select B5 to your MAX
- Paste Special -> Multiply
- Should look correct

---

You could use your B data and change C to be a formula "=B5*$D$2". 
Then drag that down and D2 should stay the same, while B5 becomes B6 and so on. 
The results should be correct to your specification.

I hope this helped!

If I get 2 more rep--I can post you a picture of it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a formula? So it will work if I just enter a value in column B (from B5 downwards), without copy and pasting?

Comment: I revised my answer to better fit your request.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply using a formula, use the $D$2 reference to your multiplier to lock in the cell d2

This tip Emeria mentioned is exactly the way to do it. Keep in mind that you can set the $ on the Row (i.e. D$2) or the Column ($D2) or both ($D$2) and then when you drag using the little square in a selection down, the NON-$ range reference will increment, but the one with the $ will not.

google "locking a range reference excel"

hope this helps if so please vote me up I'm trying to get some points!